# Autodesk Forge .Net app for reporting BIM360 docs models parameter's values

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

After doing some research about the autodesk forge I found myself overwhelmed with lots of branches and different API's.

All I'm looking for is a way to create an online forge app with a button which will query some parameter's from Revit models hosted in BIM360 cloud and display the values to the user.

Since this is a very specific thing, I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction becuase I have no idea where to start with this, I'm developing with C# over .Net with Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going to the [Autodesk Platform Services (APS) (ex-Forge) blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog). It provides search functionality, so searching for BIM360, Revit, parameter, etc. will quickly point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still a lot to proccess at once, is there a good "hello world" video tutorial for begginers about how to use the BIM360 API and the Desgin Automation API ?